# Pass data from model to view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

- How do I get the data from the CameraService after the videoClips array is populated from a button in the CameraView.
- I would like to be able to press a button and move to a new screen passing along an array of AVPlayerItems.
- My button always prints 0 even after I know there is data in the array in the CameraService

```
public class CameraService: NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
     
  @Published public var videoClips = [AVPlayerItem]()

  public func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    let video: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:outputFileURL)
    videoClips.append(video)
  }
}

final class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    
  private let service = CameraService()
  var videoClips: [AVPlayerItem]

  init() {   
    videoClips = service.videoClips
  }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    
  @StateObject var model = CameraModel()

  var body: some View {
    Button("video") {
      print(model.videoClips.count)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, `model.videoClips.count` will only ever be 0, because you set `videoClips` in `init()` and then it never gets updated again.

I'm guessing that you're assuming it'll be updated because `CameraService.videoClips` is a `@Published` property. But, `@Published` only gets watched automatically by `View`s and their `ObservableObject`s. So, two problems here: a) `CameraService` is not an `ObservableObject` and `CameraModel` is not a `View`.

My first recommendation fix this would be to ditch `CameraModel` completely. Maybe it's a function of trying to make a minimal example, but in its current form, it's not doing anything -- it's just a non-functional middleman. So, turn `CameraService` into an `ObservableObject`, which would mean that the `@Published` property would work and you'd be good-to-go.

Regarding the navigation to another screen, that's probably best for a separate question, but I'll leave a brief answer here:

```
//in your view
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(videoClips: service.videoClips)) {
  Text("Link")
}
```

(This is assuming you've turned `CameraService` into your `ObservableObject`)

If for some reason you did need both `CameraModel` and `CameraService`, you can hook up the two by doing something like this:

```
class CameraModel : ObservableObject {
    private let service = CameraService()
    @Published var videoClips : [AVPlayerItem] = [] //note that this is @Published now
        
    init() {
        service.$videoClips.assign(to: &self.$videoClips) //use a Combine Publisher to get updates from the CameraService videoClips and assign them to this class's videoClips any time there's an update 
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Now getting this error.

`Count<Publisher>(upstream: Combine.Published<Swift.Array<Foundation. AVPlayerItem >>.Publisher(subject: Combine.PublishedSubject<Swift.Array<Foundation. AVPlayerItem >>))`

Comment: I'm not seeing an error in that -- is that a partial quote? Perhaps update your question with the full error and what line it happens on?